# Error when trying to get data from XML via responseXML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I try to create a new procedure to getting real currency exchange rates from website. To do this one, i use OLE Automation Stored Procedures. But i have encountered a problem when i trying to get data with sp_OAGetProperty from XML.

When i try to inserted a XML into a temporary table with sp_OASetProperty, it gives me an error. I tried many things to fix that but that solutions mostly about XML and i don't know about XML very much. Here is the problematic part of my code:

```
    DECLARE @OBJ AS INT
    DECLARE @RESULT AS INT

EXEC @RESULT=sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @OBJ OUT 
EXEC @RESULT=sp_OAMethod @OBJ , 'open' , null , 'GET', @url, false
EXEC @RESULT=sp_OAMethod @OBJ, SEND, NULL,''

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#XML') IS NOT Null DROP TABLE #XML

    CREATE TABLE #XML (STRXML VARCHAR(max))
    INSERT INTO #XML (STRXML) EXEC @RESULT = sp_OASetProperty @OBJ,'responseXML.xml' ---> I am getting an error in this stage.

     SELECT * FROM #XML
```

I expect the xml like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?> <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="isokur.xsl"?>  <Tarih_Date Tarih="18.09.2019" Date="09/18/2019" Bulten_No="2019/175">   .......  </Tarih_Date>
```

But the output is an empty result. When i exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo to get error it shows that error:

```
  Error Code: 0x80042727
  Description: sp_OASetProperty usage:  ObjPointer int IN, PropertyName varchar IN, @setval <any> IN [, additional indexing IN params].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to use an SQL CLR stored procedure to make web service calls and avoid `MSXML2.XMLHTTP`. `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` in particular, and OLE objects in general, are not thread safe meaning that concurrent calls from SQL may cause problems.

The following, based on [Call a webservice from TSQL (Stored Procedure) using MSXML](http://www.vishalseth.com/post/2009/12/22/Call-a-webservice-from-TSQL-(Stored-Procedure)-using-MSXML.aspx), does work on SQL Server 2017 (64-bit)...

```sql
/*
exec sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1
go
reconfigure
go
*/
declare @TableVariable table (result nvarchar(max));
declare @hResult int, @object int, @Status nvarchar(max), @StatusText nvarchar(max), @Response nvarchar(max)
declare @url nvarchar(max) = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=8.8.8.8'

declare @FailPoint nvarchar(max) = 'Create'
exec @hResult = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @object out
if (@hResult = 0)
begin
    set @FailPoint = 'Open'
    exec @hResult = sp_OAMethod @object , 'Open', null, 'GET', @url, 0
end
if (@hResult = 0)
begin 
    set @FailPoint = 'Send'
    exec @hResult = sp_OAMethod @object, 'Send'
end
if (@hResult = 0)
begin
    set @FailPoint = 'Status'
    delete @TableVariable
    insert @TableVariable exec @hResult = sp_OAMethod @object, 'Status'
    select @Status=result from @TableVariable;
end
if (@hResult = 0)
begin
    set @FailPoint = 'StatusText'
    delete @TableVariable
    insert @TableVariable exec @hResult = sp_OAMethod @object, 'StatusText'
    select @StatusText=result from @TableVariable
end
if (@hResult = 0)
begin
    set @FailPoint = 'ResponseText'
    delete @TableVariable
    insert @TableVariable exec @hResult = sp_OAMethod @object, 'ResponseText'
    select @Response=result from @TableVariable
end
if (@hResult != 0)
begin
    declare @Source nvarchar(max), @Description nvarchar(max)
    exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @object, @Source out, @Description out
    select
        hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult),
        Source = @Source,
        Description = @Description,
        FailPoint = @FailPoint
    goto Destroy 
end
select [Status]=@Status, [StatusText]=@StatusText, [Response]=@Response
Destroy:
    exec @hResult = sp_OADestroy @object
go
```

If you're confident that the response is valid XML then you can follow up with `cast(@Response as xml)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer works for me. And next time i will use SQL CLR stored procedures to make web service calls as your advise.